# jpgraph - SetCenter does not work

Tags: php, jpgraph

Happy new year everybody,

today i downloaded jpgrap and looked on the examples.
I want to create a pie chart that has a legend on the left side and the graph on the right side.

On the web i found that the function SetCenter should move the graph but it does not work. The graph is always displayed on the center.

Here is my code

```
<?php
require_once ('jpgraph/src/jpgraph.php');
require_once ('jpgraph/src/jpgraph_pie.php');

$strSql = "SELECT
                YEAR(Datum) AS JAHR
            FROM kart_rundenzeiten_kopf
            WHERE
                BahnID = '".$_SESSION['KART_STATISTIK_BAHN_ID']."'
            GROUP BY YEAR(Datum)
            ORDER BY JAHR DESC";
$result = mysql_query($strSql) or die("MySQL-Error: ".mysql_error());

$strLR = 'L';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $intJahr = $row['JAHR'];

    switch( $strLR )
    {
        case 'L':
            {
                $strFloat = 'left';
                $strLR = 'R';
            } break;

        case 'R':
            {
                $strFloat = 'right';
                $strLR = 'L';
            } break;
    }
?>
    <div style="display:block; float:<?php echo $strFloat; ?>; width:49.5%;">
        <div class="div_hauptbereich" style="display:block;">
            <?php
            $strSql2 = "SELECT
                            FLOOR( (A.Rundenzeit / 1000) ) AS RUNDENZEIT,
                            COUNT(*) AS ANZAHL
                        FROM kart_rundenzeiten_posten A
                        LEFT JOIN kart_rundenzeiten_kopf B ON A.BahnID = B.BahnID AND A.RundenID = B.KopfID
                        WHERE
                            B.BahnID = '".$_SESSION['KART_STATISTIK_BAHN_ID']."'
                            AND B.Strecke = '".$_SESSION['KART_STATISTIK_STRECKEN_ID']."'
                            AND YEAR(B.Datum) = '".$intJahr."'
                        GROUP BY FLOOR( (A.Rundenzeit / 1000) )
                        ORDER BY RUNDENZEIT";
            $result2 = mysql_query($strSql2) or die("MySQL-Error: ".mysql_error());

            $arrayData = array();
            $arrayLegende = array();

            while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
            {
                $strZeit = Sekunden_In_Zeit( $row2['RUNDENZEIT'] );
                $intAnzahl = $row2['ANZAHL'];

                array_push( $arrayData, $intAnzahl );
                array_push( $arrayLegende, $strZeit.' - '.$intAnzahl.'x' );
            }

            print_r($arrayData);

            unlink("programme/kart/statistiken/charts/alle_zeiten_".$intJahr."_pie.png");

            $graph = new PieGraph(670,400,"auto");
            $graph->SetShadow();

            $graph->title->Set($intJahr);
            $graph->title->SetFont(FF_ARIAL,FS_BOLD,20);
            $graph->title->SetColor('#4444FF');

            $p1 = new PiePlot($arrayData);

            $p1->SetSize(0.3);
            $p1->SetCenter(0.35,0.5);

            $p1->value->SetFont(FF_FONT1);
            $p1->value->SetColor("black");

            $p1->SetLabelType(PIE_VALUE_ABS);

            $p1->value->SetFormat("%d");
            $p1->value->HideZero();
            $p1->value->Show();

            $p1->SetLegends( $arrayLegende );
            $graph->legend->Pos(0.73,0.05);
            $graph->legend->SetColumns(2);

            $graph->Add($p1);
            $graph->Stroke("programme/kart/statistiken/charts/alle_zeiten_".$intJahr."_pie.png");
            ?>

            <img src="programme/kart/statistiken/charts/alle_zeiten_<?php echo $intJahr; ?>_pie.png">
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Are there any settings i have to change in php?
I am working with Firefox 34 but i also tried it with IE 11.

I hope someone can help me with this problem.

Comment: could you add some (stripped down) HTML you are getting? It is difficult to judge this from the PHP alone.

Comment: i added an answer with the whole php file. Do you can work with that?

Comment: I was obviously not clear enough with my request. It is difficult to determine what HTML your browser is getting if we can just see the PHP. I was asking for the *relevant* HTML you are getting *in the browser*. You should add it to your question instead of adding it as an answer (I think all users are allowed to edit their own questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good Morning,

i found the problem. The function

```
$p1->SetCenter(0.35,0.5);
```

will be executed correctly. But the problem is in the theme classes. In this classes the SetCenter function are resetting the position.

As solution there are different possibilties:
1. By default the UniversalTheme.class.php is used where you can remove the line SetCenter. Im my case it is the PiePlot-Case.

```
function ApplyPlot($plot) {
    switch (get_class($plot))
    { 
        ...

        case 'PiePlot':
        {
            $plot->SetCenter(0.5, 0.45);
            $plot->ShowBorder(false);
            $plot->SetSliceColors($this->GetThemeColors());
            break;
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

2. Create a new theme class in folder **themes**. The theme class will be called like the following example

   unlink("programme/kart/statistiken/charts/alle_zeiten_".$intJahr."_pie.png");

   $graph = new PieGraph(670,400,"auto");
   $graph->SetShadow();

   $graph->title->Set($intJahr);
   $graph->title->SetFont(FF_ARIAL,FS_BOLD,20);
   $graph->title->SetColor('#4444FF');

   $p1 = new PiePlot($arrayData);

   **$themeClass = new KartTheme;**
   **$graph->SetTheme($themeClass);**